# How to get Nested array from local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, local-storage

I am storing user data in local storage after successful user login in angular

```
let authObservable: Observable<any>;
   authObservable = this._authService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value);
   authObservable.subscribe(
   result=> {
     localStorage.setItem('id', result['id']);
     localStorage.setItem('username', result['username']);
     localStorage.setItem('email', result['email']);
     localStorage.setItem('tokens', result['tokens']); }
```

i can get value of id and other key value

```
localstorage.getItem('id');
localstorage.getItem('username');
localstorage.getItem('email');
```

but token contain another array

```
localstorage.getItem('tokens')
// it return an array
   "tokens": "{'access': 'access_token', 'refresh': 'refresh_token_value'}"
```

how can i get tokens value and access token value and store it in refresh_token and access_token variables.
like localstorage.getItem('tokens').access

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse to JSON, like this:

```js
JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('tokens')).access
```

Comment: Can you send here the console.log of JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('tokens'))

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
"{'refresh': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYyMTY5NTM0OSwianRpIjoiMzE0MDhkODBmZDk5NGVmMDhiYzRiNWNiMTdhNTY5OTEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.GGmxZ7MSSGjrvdWKHfUjMuH1Pa8lk06l3rdtM5HlbPA', 'access': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjIxNjA5MjQ5LCJqdGkiOiI4ODQ3ZmI3OGYyYWE0NDRkOWUzNGNmOGE3NjNiNGYwZiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.PO1hjkaBY6zl9DdGDz5Vc9ug654RuhZGHn9-_X8bnhs'}"
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).access;
undefined `

Comment: did you put the slashes when parsing the result ?, mine still not worked

Comment: Yes, I put it because the right json needs to have double quotes instead of a single quote, so I needed to change it to make a right conversion